# Published an app on Gplay. After installing, I can never open the app

Tags: android, google-play

I just published my app on Google Play and during testing with the simulator and the phone itself, everything worked just fine.

Now, after publishing the APK and installing it on my phone from Google Play Store, I simply can't open the app. The "open" button in my app's Google Play Store doesn't even exist.

Google changed from that APK page to Release Management and I wonder if I am doing something wrong.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9hFu.jpg

Any help?
Thanks

EDIT:

Following requests, this is the important part of my Android Manifest:

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginSignupActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login_signup"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="www.example.com"
                    android:path="/deeplink_invite"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

So notice that I have added a deep link action and Main/Launcher actions to the same activity.
I am thinking that is the issue.
I will put the deep link to the MainActivity and if the user clicks on a link, he will be taken to MainActivity - but if he's not logged in, he must go to Login.

I will release the APK with these change and let you guys know.

Comment: Can you show us the AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you have described intent-filters in AndroidManifest.xml

Eg:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/ActivityWithoutActionBar">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Yep , that was it. Seems like an Activity can only have one Main/Launcher activity and nothing else? I changed to what I described above and it worked. Thanks!